# Determine Zodiac sign and weekday of birth

Tags: vb.net

Hey, I need to make a program in vb.net that asks for the user's birthday. The program should give the day of the week the person was born and their astrological star sign. Can anybody help me?? PLEASE!

Comment: What have you tried so far? Are there some problems you ran into when you tried to solve this problem that you would like to ask about?

Comment: I can't figure out where to start. I know I have to get the present date and the date entered by the user, but there I'm stuck

Comment: The VB.NET DateTime class has DayOfWeek. Star sign you'll just have to code in the date ranges for each sign. Isn't that all there is to this?

Comment: Yeah. Thank you very much. Can you please show me an example of that Function?

Comment: It seems you spend more time asking than you could do by just trying it out...

Comment: I don't have a programming platform right now. I just wanted an example. And if I don't ask, then I'll never know

Comment: All you'll get with this is a bunch of people willing to write your program .. and that isn't what Stack Overflow facilitates.

Answer (score 2):

```
Private Function Zodiac(ByVal Birthday As Date) As String
  Dim year As Integer = Birthday.Year
  Dim zodiacs = {
    New With {.From = New Date(year, 1, 1), .[To] = New Date(year, 1, 19), .Zodiac = "Capricorn"},
    New With {.From = New Date(year, 1, 20), .[To] = New Date(year, 2, 18), .Zodiac = "Aquarius"},
    New With {.From = New Date(year, 2, 19), .[To] = New Date(year, 3, 20), .Zodiac = "Pisces"},
    New With {.From = New Date(year, 3, 21), .[To] = New Date(year, 4, 19), .Zodiac = "Aries"},
    New With {.From = New Date(year, 4, 20), .[To] = New Date(year, 5, 20), .Zodiac = "Taurus"},
    New With {.From = New Date(year, 5, 21), .[To] = New Date(year, 6, 20), .Zodiac = "Gemini"},
    New With {.From = New Date(year, 6, 21), .[To] = New Date(year, 7, 22), .Zodiac = "Cancer"},
    New With {.From = New Date(year, 7, 23), .[To] = New Date(year, 8, 22), .Zodiac = "Leo"},
    New With {.From = New Date(year, 8, 23), .[To] = New Date(year, 9, 22), .Zodiac = "Virgo"},
    New With {.From = New Date(year, 9, 23), .[To] = New Date(year, 10, 22), .Zodiac = "Libra"},
    New With {.From = New Date(year, 10, 23), .[To] = New Date(year, 11, 21), .Zodiac = "Scorpio"},
    New With {.From = New Date(year, 11, 22), .[To] = New Date(year, 12, 21), .Zodiac = "Sagittarius"},
    New With {.From = New Date(year, 12, 22), .[To] = New Date(year, 12, 31), .Zodiac = "Capricorn"}}

  Return (From z In zodiacs Where (z.From <= Birthday And Birthday <= z.[To])).Single.Zodiac
End Function
```

The first, crappy attempt:

```
Private Function Zodiac(ByVal Birthday As Date) As String
  Dim year As Integer = Birthday.Year
  Dim sodiacCapricorn() As DateTime = {New DateTime(year, 12, 22), New DateTime(year, 1, 19)}
  Dim sodiacAquarius() As DateTime = {New DateTime(year, 1, 20), New DateTime(year, 2, 18)}
  Dim sodiacPisces() As DateTime = {New DateTime(year, 2, 19), New DateTime(year, 3, 20)}
  Dim sodiacAries() As DateTime = {New DateTime(year, 3, 21), New DateTime(year, 4, 19)}
  Dim sodiacTaurus() As DateTime = {New DateTime(year, 4, 20), New DateTime(year, 5, 20)}
  Dim sodiacGemini() As DateTime = {New DateTime(year, 5, 21), New DateTime(year, 6, 20)}
  Dim sodiacCancer() As DateTime = {New DateTime(year, 6, 21), New DateTime(year, 7, 22)}
  Dim sodiacLeo() As DateTime = {New DateTime(year, 7, 23), New DateTime(year, 8, 22)}
  Dim sodiacVirgo() As DateTime = {New DateTime(year, 8, 23), New DateTime(year, 9, 22)}
  Dim sodiacLibra() As DateTime = {New DateTime(year, 9, 23), New DateTime(year, 10, 22)}
  Dim sodiacScorpio() As DateTime = {New DateTime(year, 10, 23), New DateTime(year, 11, 21)}
  Dim sodiacSagittarius() As DateTime = {New DateTime(year, 11, 22), New DateTime(year, 12, 21)}

  Select Case Birthday.DayOfYear
    Case 1 To sodiacCapricorn(1).DayOfYear, sodiacCapricorn(0).DayOfYear To 366
      Return "Capricorn"
    Case sodiacAquarius(0).DayOfYear To sodiacAquarius(1).DayOfYear
      Return "Aquarius"
    Case sodiacPisces(0).DayOfYear To sodiacPisces(1).DayOfYear
      Return "Pisces"
    Case sodiacAries(0).DayOfYear To sodiacAries(1).DayOfYear
      Return "Aries"
    Case sodiacTaurus(0).DayOfYear To sodiacTaurus(1).DayOfYear
      Return "Taurus"
    Case sodiacGemini(0).DayOfYear To sodiacGemini(1).DayOfYear
      Return "Gemini"
    Case sodiacCancer(0).DayOfYear To sodiacCancer(1).DayOfYear
      Return "Cancer"
    Case sodiacLeo(0).DayOfYear To sodiacLeo(1).DayOfYear
      Return "Leo"
    Case sodiacVirgo(0).DayOfYear To sodiacVirgo(1).DayOfYear
      Return "Virgo"
    Case sodiacLibra(0).DayOfYear To sodiacLibra(1).DayOfYear
      Return "Libra"
    Case sodiacScorpio(0).DayOfYear To sodiacScorpio(1).DayOfYear
      Return "Scorpio"
    Case sodiacSagittarius(0).DayOfYear To sodiacSagittarius(1).DayOfYear
      Return "Sagittarius"
    Case Else
      Return "?"
  End Select
End Function
```

The use of annomous types and a single neat LINQ statement is way more readable IMHO.

Comment: My eyes!!!!  Wouldn't it be easier to use a select case statement?

Comment: I did! That was my first attempt, and that was way more horrific. Let me add it back in...

Comment: I think it might be better to use a CONST for the dates as they are in effect magic numbers.  If they were defined external to the function, it would also tidy things up a bit.  Not trying to be overly critical, sorry if it comes off that way, just trying to help!

Comment: I agree. Normally I would put something like The Zodiac array somewhere outside the function. But this keeps it pretty tidy and because the data structure is so simple, I also think it would be overkill to declare a class to hold the values. They'll NEVER change.

Comment: I think making the date array a `Static` would be good as it would be initialized only once.